# Test mail is working but when i configured post build email notification doesn't works

Tags: jenkins

When i configured email notification in Jenkins, test mail is working but post build "E-mail Notification" doesn't work properly.

[image]

```
Sending e-mails to: samplemail@gmail.com
ERROR: [EOF]
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: [EOF]
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1862)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1100)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at hudson.tasks.MailSender.run(MailSender.java:131)
at hudson.tasks.Mailer.perform(Mailer.java:171)
at
hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform
(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at 
hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform
(AbstractBuild.java:744)
at 
hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps
(AbstractBuild.java:690)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
at 
hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post
(AbstractBuild.java:635)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1823)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using in the pipeline?

Comment: I am not using any code. i am just configure Email Notification plugin and provide Smtp server address and authentication mail id & password. when i was gave mail id for test purpose it's working successfully but when i configured in post build action it doesn't send mails if my build is failured